# Shopping Cart - Array not storing a value

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to create a shopping cart where the user can enter the number of items he/she has purchased and the price for each item.
I am having problems with the array. I am not able to store the price for each product. How can I store the second value (the price) in an array to match each item?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[][] itemsCart;
    int itemsInTheCart=0;
    int itemsPrice = 0;

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of items in your cart: ");
    itemsInTheCart = scan.nextInt();

     for(int i = 0; i < itemsInTheCart; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter the price for item " + (i+1) + ": ");

        itemsPrice = scan.nextInt();

        itemsCart = new int[itemsPrice][itemsPrice];

        // System.out.println(itemsCart.length);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array needs to be declared with its size before it can be used.

Also in your example you do not need a 2D array, a 1D array is fine.

Also you need to initialize your array outside the loop other wise it will get overridden in each iteration

```
System.out.print("Please enter the number of items in your cart: ");
itemsInTheCart = scan.nextInt();
int [] itemsCart = new int [itemsInTheCart];

for (....) {

    itemsCart[i] = itemsPrice;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead Use `ArrayList`

for example create a object class

```
class ShoppingDetails{
    private String itemName;
    private Integer price;

    public ShoppingDetails(String itemName, Integer price) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.price = price;
    }
    //add getter and setter if you want
}
```

Now you can use the it in

```
ArrayList<ShoppingDetails> shoppingCart=new ArrayList<>();


shoppingCart.add(new ShoppingDetails("item1",100);
```

By this way you can map price to items.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @"Scary Wombat", your approach is better suited for a 1D array than a 2D one. However since you are looking to use a 2D array I would like to point your where you code could be better. Also mentioned by him to need to declare the size before using the 2D array

Your line "itemsCart = new int[itemsPrice][itemsPrice];" would be better as         itemsCart = new int[i][itemsPrice]; as this will ensure that the new indexes are filled with the appropriate values.

I have made some edits to your main. Feel free to as me if you don't understand

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[][] itemsCart;
    int itemsInTheCart=0;
    int itemsPrice = 0;
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of items in your cart: ");
    itemsInTheCart = scan.nextInt();
    itemsCart= new int[itemsInTheCart][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < itemsInTheCart; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter the price for item " + (i+1) + ": ");

        itemsPrice = scan.nextInt();

        itemsCart[i][1] = itemsPrice;
    }
    // for testing
    for (int i=0;i<itemsInTheCart;i++){
        System.out.println("Item: "+(i+1)+" for price: "+ itemsCart[i][1] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{

 public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int itemsInTheCart=0;
System.out.print("Please enter the number of items in your cart: ");
itemsInTheCart = scan.nextInt();
int[] itemsCart = new int[itemsInTheCart]; 

 for(int i = 0; i < itemsInTheCart; i++){
    System.out.print("Enter the price for item " + (i+1) + ": ");
    itemsCart[i] = scan.nextInt();
}

 for(int i = 0; i < itemsInTheCart; i++){

     System.out.println(itemsCart[i]);
     }
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't Give negative reviews unnecessary. Mention a reason where is the mistake before doing that. it may helpful for me to rectifying mistakes